# Unable to Use nest.js imports with Angular @NgModule decorator

Tags: angular

Trying to Merge Nest.js REST API to Angular Backend.

I have a module I built with Nest.js that uses the @Module decorator. I am trying to import this into my app.module.ts file but I am getting the error 'Module' does not appear to be an @NgModule Class(-996002).

In the module class I try to change it from @Module decorator to @NgModel decorator but it is throwing an error.

Seems like a mismatch between how Angular wants me to do things versus how Nest.js wants me to do things.